# Silverlight video conference

Tags: silverlight, iis, stream, live

I am developing a silverlight video conference application which will support multicast. I want to know which technology is best, socket coding or IIS live smooth streaming. The performance is the big issue, Thanks T.

Answer (score 0):

Protocol decision depends on many parameters. For example what are the expectations for latency? Are you looking at true conference experience with <500ms latency or is several seconds latency is fine? How many clients are going to be connected at the same time? Is it internet or intranet?

Comment: Latency may be 5 seconds allow. it will be internet application and it may be 10/25/50/100 or more than 200 connection at a time.

Comment: Is it a conference or broadcast? How many endpoints are going to send data at once? If only one endpoint is going to send, IIS live streaming solution is probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you Ozeki Voip SIP SDK and its webphone solutions. After testing it in Visual Studio 2010 I went on using it. It sounds a bit like sticking to this sdk, but I have experienced that the support team  is really good: they have helped me significantly in my work. I found **How to implement web to web video calls using Silverlight camera access? to be a good sample program on their website and think it would be instructive enough for you to start a business application with webphone.

Hopefully I could help you.